# Android Studio emulator suddenly becomes very slow after windows 10 update

Tags: android, windows, android-emulator

I have been using Android studio and emulator together and so far I have not experienced any lag (OK, only a little). I updated Windows 10 to the **October 2020 update** (as they called it), but now, anytime I launch the android emulator from Android Studio I noticed that it took **3x** the normal startup time and afterwards, it becomes extremely slow. I have HAXM installed already on my Intel PC. What could be the problem?

Comment: Check if haxm really works - run `sc query intelhaxm`.

Comment: I got this:SERVICE_NAME: intelhaxm
        TYPE               : 1  KERNEL_DRIVER
        STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                                (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0

Comment: What's your haxm version? A year old version had a bug that lead to slowdown due to windows meltdown/spectre mitigations. Maybe upgrading haxm to latest version will help.

Comment: I have never updated HAXM, I never see an "update available" message in android studio. How would I update it.

Comment: This is the latest version - https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases/tag/v7.6.5. Download it and run the installer.

Comment: Done that. Same issue

Comment: Create an issue at github.com/intel/haxm, it's possible a haxm bug.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that, but thanks, I'll do just that. But does that mean that I should now pause development for this ?

Comment: A haxm version is to be released in 2 or 3 weeks. The next one will be released in 3 or more months. When it's a haxm bug, you will not get a working version in less than 3 months. It's up to you to decide if you can pause development for so long.

Comment: ok. thanks. but can Genymotion serve as a replacement while I wait